# How do I cut off overflowing audio using Melt?

Tags: video-editing, melt

I am trying to cut away the overflowing audio from a track generated in Melt. The audio is a lot longer than the video, and I don't necessarily know the length of either.

```
V=Video, A=Audio

    VVVVVVV
    AAAAAAAAAAAA
          ^^
    This is where I want the cut.
```

Can anybody help me with that please? :)